# Number theory book by Borevich and Shafarevich

Tags: book-recommendation, reference-works

I just saw a book of Number Theory by Borevich and Shafarevich. It is currently not in print.

On the other hand, there are many volumes of Number Theory (I, II, III, IV etc) by Shafarevich by Springer, which are in print.

I want to know, whether the old book of number theory is reshaped in Springer series among I, II, III etc? (i.e. whether the content of old edition is put with modification in new books among I, II, III etc.)?

Comment: Will be good to give Details about the In-Print Books , I am not able to figure it out. In the meantime , I think , maybe there is some over-lap between the Books , but the Earlier Book was Co-Authored with a Peer , while the newer Book(s) are either Edited by or Authored by Shafarevich (maybe Co-Authored with students) thus it will be plagiarism if it was just shuffled around or reshaped by Springer without listing the Original Co-Author. I think , the new Book(s) must be unrelated.